# Custom directive not rendered on specified DOM location

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Solution: this directive should be restricted to 'A' (attribute) instead of 'E' (element), since it extends the functionality of an regular table row

Given this tabel markup:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="val in [1,2,3]">header {{val}}</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <row-directive ng-repeat="(row, index) in [1,2,3]" row-index="{{$index}}"></row-directive>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and this directive:

```
angular.module('gguiApp').directive('rowDirective', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: false,
    scope:{
      rowIndex : '@'
    },
    template: '<tr><td ng-repeat="x in [1,2,3]"> cell {{x}} of row {{rowIndex}}</tr>'
};
});
```

I would expect that the tbody is filled with elements produced by my custom directive. This does not happen.

The result I get is:
[image: screenshot of wrong rendered table]

Which is not what I want. Why is my directive not rendered at the expected location?

Appendix:

The source of the rendered table:

```
<div class="container">
<!-- ngRepeat: (row, index) in [1,2,3] --><row-directive ng-repeat="(row, index) in [1,2,3]" row-index="0" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope"><tr><!-- ngRepeat: x in [1,2,3] --><td ng-repeat="x in [1,2,3]" class="ng-binding ng-scope"> cell 1 of row 0</td><!-- end ngRepeat: x in [1,2,3] --><td ng-repeat="x in [1,2,3]" class="ng-binding ng-scope"> cell 2 of row 0</td><!-- end ngRepeat: x in [1,2,3] --><td ng-repeat="x in [1,2,3]" class="ng-binding ng-scope"> cell 3 of row 0</td><!-- end ngRepeat: x in [1,2,3] --></tr></row-directive><!-- end ngRepeat: (row, index) in [1,2,3] --><row-directive ng-repeat="(row, index) in [1,2,3]" row-index="1" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope"><tr><!-- ngRepeat: x in [1,2,3] --><td ng-repeat="x in [1,2,3]" class="ng-binding ng-scope"> cell 1 of row 1</td><!-- end ngRepeat: x in [1,2,3] --><td ng-repeat="x in [1,2,3]" class="ng-binding ng-scope"> cell 2 of row 1</td><!-- end ngRepeat: x in [1,2,3] --><td ng-repeat="x in [1,2,3]" class="ng-binding ng-scope"> cell 3 of row 1</td><!-- end ngRepeat: x in [1,2,3] --></tr></row-directive><!-- end ngRepeat: (row, index) in [1,2,3] --><row-directive ng-repeat="(row, index) in [1,2,3]" row-index="2" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope"><tr><!-- ngRepeat: x in [1,2,3] --><td ng-repeat="x in [1,2,3]" class="ng-binding ng-scope"> cell 1 of row 2</td><!-- end ngRepeat: x in [1,2,3] --><td ng-repeat="x in [1,2,3]" class="ng-binding ng-scope"> cell 2 of row 2</td><!-- end ngRepeat: x in [1,2,3] --><td ng-repeat="x in [1,2,3]" class="ng-binding ng-scope"> cell 3 of row 2</td><!-- end ngRepeat: x in [1,2,3] --></tr></row-directive><!-- end ngRepeat: (row, index) in [1,2,3] --><table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <!-- ngRepeat: val in [1,2,3] --><th ng-repeat="val in [1,2,3]" class="ng-binding ng-scope">header 1</th><!-- end ngRepeat: val in [1,2,3] --><th ng-repeat="val in [1,2,3]" class="ng-binding ng-scope">header 2</th><!-- end ngRepeat: val in [1,2,3] --><th ng-repeat="val in [1,2,3]" class="ng-binding ng-scope">header 3</th><!-- end ngRepeat: val in [1,2,3] -->
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
<!--<div ui-view="loginView"></div>-->
<!--<div ui-view="appView"></div>-->
```

Comment: try adding replace:true to your directive,

Comment: `replace` is deprecated

Comment: maybe this issue could help: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1459

Comment: if your angular version doesn't support replace then consider moving your directive into an attribute or a class and use the <tr> element as its root since your problem seems to me is that you are trying to put non valid html inside the table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with an attribute directive because from what i understand from this post: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1459, the browser will move your custom element directive outside the table when parsing the page.

```
<tbody>
<tr row-directive ng-repeat="(row, index) in [1,2,3]" row-index="{{$index}}"></tr>
</tbody>
```

directive:

```
angular.module('gguiApp').directive('rowDirective', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    scope:{
      rowIndex : '@'
    },
    template: '<td ng-repeat="x in [1,2,3]"> cell {{x}} of row {{rowIndex}}</td>'
};
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/10616/)